# Why is this error coming out and how do I solve it?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication, recaptcha

I am making a messenger app on Kotlin and encountered this problem,

2020-11-18 14:20: 41.163 18185-18185/com.example.vinco E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token - calling backend without app verification

I'll leave the class codes below

class EnterPhoneNumberFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_enter_phone_number) {

```
private lateinit var mPhoneNumber:String
private lateinit var mCallback:PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    AUTH = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    initFirebase() ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    mCallback = object :PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            AUTH.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    showToast("Добро пожаловать")
                    (activity as RegisterActivity).replaceActivity(MainActivity())
                }else showToast(task.exception?.message.toString())
            }
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
           // showToast(p0.message.toString())
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(id: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            replaceFragment(EnterCodeFragment(mPhoneNumber,id))

        }
    }
    register_btn_next.setOnClickListener{ sendCode()}
}

private fun sendCode(){
    if (register_input_phone_number.text.toString().isEmpty()){
        showToast(getString(R.string.register_toast_enter_phone))
    }else{
        authUser()
    }

}



private fun authUser() {
   mPhoneNumber = register_input_phone_number.text.toString()

    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
        .setPhoneNumber(mPhoneNumber)
        .setTimeout(60L,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setActivity(activity as RegisterActivity)
        .setCallbacks(mCallback)
        .build()

    )
}
```

### }

class EnterCodeFragment(private val phoneNumber: String, val id: String) : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_enter_code) {

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    (activity as RegisterActivity).title = phoneNumber
    register_input_code.addTextChangedListener ( AppTextWatcher{
        initFirebase()
            val string = register_input_code.text.toString()
            if(string.length==6) {
                enterCode()
            }

    } )



}
private fun enterCode(){

    val code = register_input_code.text.toString()
    val credential:PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(id, code)


    AUTH.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if(task.isSuccessful){
            val uid:String = AUTH.currentUser?.uid.toString()
            val dateMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
            dateMap[CHILD_ID] = uid
            dateMap[CHILD_PHONE] = phoneNumber
            dateMap[CHILD_USERNAME] = uid

            REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_USERS).child(uid).updateChildren(dateMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener{ task2 ->
                if (task2.isSuccessful) {
                    showToast("Добро пожаловать")
                    (activity as RegisterActivity).replaceActivity(MainActivity())
                }else showToast(task2.exception?.message.toString())
                }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```